# Insert multiple data into mysql database table using while loop

Tags: php, mysql

the script is supposed to insert multiple data into the database
 but for some reason its inserting only the first data. This is the aspect of my code that gives the issue.

```
$pledge_amount = "400";
$getDonors = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM `highck39_earn`.`users` WHERE `tomerge` = '2' AND `role`='0' AND `status` = '0'  AND `username` != '$username' ORDER BY `reward_date` ASC LIMIT 0, 2"); 

    $i=0;
    while($resultObj = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getDonors)){

          $rewardBal = $resultObj['reward_balance'];
          $ind_amt = $pledge_amount/2;

         $do_donation = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `highck39_earn`.`donations` (`id`, `transaction_id`, `sender`, `sender_name`, `sender_number`, `sender_momo_number`, `receiver`, `receiver_name`, `receiver_number`, `receiver_momo_number`, `amount`, `date`, `status`) VALUES (NULL, '{$transcode}', '{$username}', '{$fullname}', '{$phone}', '{$momo}', '{$resultObj['username']}', '{$resultObj['fullname']}', '{$resultObj['phone']}', '{$resultObj['momo']}', '{$ind_amt}', '{$pledge_date}', '1')");

          $i++;
          echo $i;
          echo $resultObj['fullname']. ' - '. $ind_amt.'<br>';    
          // if($cnt % 2 == 0) echo "<br>";


          // $data2 = array("fullname" => $fullname, "receiver"=>$resultObj['fullname']);
            //echo json_encode($data2,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT); 
    }
```

Comment: What is `$i` after the loop ends?

Comment: You can do this with 1 query. Look into `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` syntax that MySQL supports. Google literally that part that I put into code highlight.

Comment: @BlobbyBob The $i prints 1 and 2 to the screen

Comment: @RichardNeaver Check the return value of `$do_donaton`. `mysqli_query()` returns false in case of an error. 
You can also have a look at `mysqli_num_rows()` which returns the number of rows inserted.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any sql error in your log when you try to do the insert ?

You can check if the insert worked correctly with something like :

```
if (mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO...") === TRUE) {
    printf("Insert ok");
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). For the moment I've added the comment for you, and I'm flagging this post for deletion.

Comment: the insert works but it only inserts just 1 record instead of the multiple records. please is there any other way of making this work, maybe a foreach or for lpoop or something

Comment: Were you able to add the check on your query to your code ? It should be displayed twice (same as the $i).